# Apache excute Rewrite Rule if URI doesn't start with strings

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am trying for my site to detect users from specific country to navigate them to other website, but if they asked for specific page, apache shouldn't nagvigate them away, in other words:

- http://website1.com/ --> Goes to: http://website2.com/
- http://website1.com/foo --> Goes to: http://website2.com/foo
- http://website1.com/wp-admin/Anything --> No change
- http://website1.com/wp-login/Anything --> No change

I set up some htaccess rules, but work only for country detecting, not page exception:

```
RewriteEngine On
GeoIPEnable On
RewriteCond %{ENV:GEOIP_COUNTRY_CODE} ^CODE$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(wpweblogin|wp-login|wp-admin).*
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://website2.com/$1 [L,NC,QSA]
```

What is wrong in the exception condition?

Comment: I'd say you need to specify the `[OR]` flag in the first `RewriteCond`, otherwise the second condition won't get evaluated by itself. The default connection between ``RewriteCond``s is an _AND_ operator which is not what you want here.

Comment: I need the `[AND]` operator not the`[OR]`, as i need the country users to stay on website1, if they requested wp-login or wp-admin, otherwise they will go to website2

Comment: You are correct, sorry, I got confused by your question.

Comment: But it doesn't work properly, as for `wpweblogin` as a customized admin login wordpress, doesn't work at all